# iOS UIImageView Position

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I need to put an image to the bottom of screen, so I used UIImageView and tried two ways to specify its position:

```
someImageView.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, a, b);
[someImageView initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, a, b)];
```

But it shows up at the top covering the navigation bar. What did I do wrong? What would you suggest to do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your values for `x,y,a,b` are the likely problem.

Comment: what is your view hierarchy? show us how you create your views and add the uiimageview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you are assuming the correct screen coordinates? The origin of the screen is in the top-left, not the bottom-left. Try adding an object in Interface Builder and inspecting its frame in there.

I am a little confused by the second line in your code snippet above. Are you calling `initWithFrame:` on an object that is already initialised? If so, you might see some unexpected behaviour. Objects should be declared:

```
UIImageView *someImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Rather than:

```
UIImageView *someImageView = [UIImageView alloc];
[someImageView initWithFrame:frame];
```

Always keep `alloc` and `init` on the same line of code.

Comment: Yes the initialization was the problem! I did the "rather than", ugh. What's the difference between these two?

Comment: @City Techno: I must admit I'm quite surprised that the initialisation was the cause of your particular problem, it was intended as more of a passing comment! Keeping alloc and init on the same line is something of a convention really, and in practice _shouldn't_ affect the implementation (so long as they are called in succession). It was calling `initWithFrame:` on an object that you have already called `init` on that I was warning might cause unexpected behaviour. Could you perhaps edit your question to show a larger snippet of your code (prior to being fixed), please?

Comment: StuDev, I'm new to iOS from a C/C++/Java background and very surprised by it very often. The reason why I did the frame later is because I did initWithImage first with alloc. After I swapped these two around it worked. Yes I will make sure this strange behavior is indeed caused by the order of these two and post more code.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that top-left of the screen is (0,0), while bottom-right is (320,460).
You may use

```
someImageView.frame=CGRectMake(320 - a, 460 - b, a, b);
```

assuming that `a` is the width and `b` is the height

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct! Check the values you are using in `CGRectMake`. For instance:

```
someImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 
   [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-ivHeight,
   [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 
   ivHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your (x,y,a,b) could be the problem. Make sure the y is > 0. Also, make sure that you are adding the frame to the correct subview. Adding it to the wrong one could cause the problem. If you are still having trouble, post the code that you are using and I could be more helpful.

Also,Do not call initWithFrame without calling alloc first. It should be:

```
someImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, a, b)];
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew. My numbers are right but should've put in one line like yours.

Comment: Also, check what autosizing constraints you've put on the UIImageView if you're using InterfaceBuilder/Storyboards. I just debugged a situation where the view wasn't quite where it should have been, due to a resizing height.